# Do I have to catch a NumberFormatException trying to parse a value to an int or long?

Tags: java

Say I have this method:

```
    public long getLongId(JWTClaimsSet claimsSet)
    {
        return Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(claimsSet.getClaim(LONG_ID_CLAIM)));
    }

    public int getIntId(JWTClaimsSet claimsSet)
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(claimsSet.getClaim(ID_CLAIM)));
    }
```

for both methods, if I don't send a valid int or long, I want the method to return the defaults, which is 0. Do I need to catch the NumberFormatException here or is this handled internally?

Comment: Look at the Javadoc, it is in there. You could also try it out.

Comment: Answer is: yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure what for data type come from JWTClaimsSet claimsSet than  is good if you exclude an potential Exception

```
 public long getLongId(JWTClaimsSet claimsSet) {
    try {
        return Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(claimsSet.getClaim(LONG_ID_CLAIM)));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
}


public int getIntId(JWTClaimsSet claimsSet) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(claimsSet.getClaim(ID_CLAIM)));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
```